Is there a Python query language tool like ClangQL?
I like the concept of CLangQL, and I wish it was available for other languages such as Python. There are certainly a variety of static analysis tools for Python, and if I didn't have so many projects on the go already I would pick up the ast lib and start writing this type of thing myself. But (1) I don't have the time, and (2) it is not wise to just start writing something before getting assurance that you're not reinventing the wheel.
Is there a close analog to ClangQL but for Python? I don't care much what it is written in (Python, C/C++, Rust, Go, ...) as long as it is cross-platform.

It is early in development, supporting primarily functions at the time of writing this, but PyQL aims to have this functionality. It is based on the same SDK as ClangQL, so the SQL-like commands should be familiar if you are familiar with ClangQL already.
